# How to remove all packages installed because of KDE on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde

I first installed Ubuntu then I wanted to try kde. 
So I did

```
sudo aptitude install --with-recommends kubuntu
```

or something similar.

When I decided I don't like it, I removed kubuntu and did autoremove.

I recently realized when I'm trying out i3 that everything in i3, terminal etc., are still in plasma style.

How could I 1. find and remove all remaining plasma packages or 2. let i3 use gnome packages rather than plasma ones.

Preferably the first option of course.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd likely have more clues if you were specific on what package you installed, plus what packages you removed (if they are the same, most should be removed!; look in your apt logs for specifics if you don't see it in history).  Either way adding a desktop causes some wallpapers, plymouth & other things to be installed; which are not removed when packages that installed them are removed. You just stop using them (eg. select your wanted ubuntu plymouth screen, etc). There is no package you can install to auto-do-that as it was done by package *post-installation* scripts.

Comment: You can see what you did install in `/var/log/apt/*`. After removing packages you installed, `sudo apt-get autoremove` will clean out the Reccomends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @waltinator, I figured out what I installed in `/var/log/aptitude` and removed them all.